# Tkinter clearing formatting from syntax highlighting

Tags: python, regex, tkinter, syntax-highlighting

I have syntax highlighting implemented in Python using Tkinter.  For example, I can make it automatically highlight "derp".  The problem is that when I modify the string to, say, "dERP"or something similar, it will still highlight the "d" (aka the only remaining original character).  How do I clear formatting on this?  I've considered creating a tag that will set the background to white for the entire document, but then this creates problems with highlighting.

code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import sys, os

class easyTex(Text):
    def __init__(self,base,**args):
        Text.__init__(self,base,**args)
        self.tag_configure("default", background="white")
        self.tag_configure("search", background="blue")

    def highlightPattern(self, pattern, tag):
        start       = "1.0"
        countVar    = StringVar()
        while True:
            pos = self.search(pattern, start, stopindex="end", count=countVar, regexp=True)
            if not pos: break
            self.tag_add(tag, pos, "%s+%sc" % (pos, countVar.get()))
            start = "%s+%dc" % (pos, int(countVar.get()) + 1)

    def highlightSyntax(self):
        self.highlightPattern(".*", "default")
        self.highlightPattern("a red car", "search")

base = Tk()
editor = easyTex(base)

base.bind("<Escape>", lambda e: sys.exit())
base.bind("<Key>", lambda e: editor.highlightSyntax())

editor.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

base.call('wm', 'attributes', '.', '-topmost', True)
mainloop()
```

(this is using the regex: "a red car":)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the issue. We can't help you if we don't know what you're doing.

Comment: MCVE added.  If you have tkinter you should be able to see test it yourself pretty easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the effects of a tag, remove the tag from the range of characters. You can remove a tag with [tag_remove](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.tag_remove-method), giving it a starting and ending range that you want the tag removed from.

For example, to remove the `"search"` tag from the entire document, do this:

```
self.tag_remove("search", "1.0", "end")
```